# Storing Oracle DB table's ROWID as a character array

Tags: c++, arrays, oracle, embedded-sql

I would like to retrieve ROWID of a table from Oracle DB and store in memory as a character array for later use. For example, I run the following query:

```
SELECT ROWID, MARKS FROM MTB WHERE EID='123';
```

Then using Pro*C, I would like to store this ROWID as a character array rrr to use later as:

```
UPDATE MTB SET MARKS = 80 WHERE ROWID='<rrr>'
```

Please help and point to appropriate documentation of Pro*C usage to convert a ROWID to an array of character strings.

Comment: You mean [rowidtochar](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions157.htm#SQLRF06101) and [chartorowid](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions025.htm#SQLRF00615)? Or something specific to C/Pro\*C?

Comment: do you mean to use ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID) instead of ROWID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ROWIDTOCHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions157.htm) and [CHARTOROWID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions025.htm) functions:

```
SELECT ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID), MARKS INTO :rrr, :marks FROM MTB WHERE EID='123';
```

And then

```
UPDATE MTB SET MARKS = 80 WHERE ROWID=CHARTOROWID(:rrr);
```